# KeyError when plotting with skimage.io

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I am sorry that the Title is not very descriptive, but my problem is very strange, at least to me.

```
image = skiio.imread("picture.png")
greyValues = []
for i in xrange(len(image)):
    greyValues.append(np.uint32(image[i][xPos]))
skimage.io.imsave("image.png",np.transpose(greyValues))
```

Now this works fine, but I want to calculate the mean of three bars along the y-Axis:

```
image = skiio.imread("picture.png")
greyValues = []
for i in xrange(len(image)):
    greyValues.append(np.uint32((np.uint32(data[i][xPos])+np.uint32(data[i][xPos-1])+np.uint32(data[i][xPos+1]))/np.uint32(3)))
skimage.io.imsave("image.png",np.transpose(greyValues))
```

So I get this error:

> File "C:\Anaconda2_x64\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py", line 43, in dtype_limits
>       imin, imax = dtype_range[image.dtype.type]

KeyError: < type 'numpy.uint32'>

In GreyValues the RGB Values are saved as eg.: [255,255,255]
At first I thought I had differnet types since I am dividing by 3 so I made sure to cast everything to a numpy.uint32, which might be a bit unnecessary, but that did not solve the problem and now I am kind of clueless what I am doing wrong.

I checked again to be 100% sure:

```
for j in xrange(len(greyValues)):
    if(greyValues[j][0].dtype!='uint32'):
        print j,type(greyValues[j])
```

Which had no output

Help would be much appreciated

**EDIT**

I looked deeper into it and I noticed that the KeyError happens here:

```
import numpy as np
dtype_range = {np.bool_: (False, True),
           np.bool8: (False, True),
           np.uint8: (0, 255),
           np.uint16: (0, 65535),
           np.int8: (-128, 127),
           np.int16: (-32768, 32767),
           np.int64: (-2**63, 2**63 - 1),
           np.uint64: (0, 2**64 - 1),
           np.int32: (-2**31, 2**31 - 1),
           np.uint32: (0, 2**32 - 1),
           np.float32: (-1, 1),
           np.float64: (-1, 1)}

def dtype_limits(image, clip_negative=True):
    """Return intensity limits, i.e. (min, max) tuple, of the image's dtype.

    Parameters
    ----------
    image : ndarray
        Input image.
    clip_negative : bool
        If True, clip the negative range (i.e. return 0 for min intensity)
        even if the image dtype allows negative values.
    """
    imin, imax = dtype_range[image.dtype.type]
    if clip_negative:
        imin = 0
    return imin, imax`
```

Now when I check with my data, and I use `np.transpose(GreyValues).dtype.type` I get that exact error,

so when I do `dtype_range[numpy.uint32]`
Spyder says

`NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined`

So is the problem that it states `np.uint32` instead of `numpy.uint32`?
But why did it work in the first place?
Also how would I get around it? should I delete the import and state it to be numpy instead of np?

Comment: Maybe too late but when you import a module, the libraries are imported and your function that includes calls to them will work. However if you execute a statement in the console outside of the function call, you need to import the libraries used in that statement in the console before execution or you get the error that the package is not defined. Your import statement `import numpy as np` is correct, do not change it.